# Is it possible to render partials in static html5 pages

Tags: html, render, partial-views

Currently writing a static website for a collage project. I would like to render a sidebar as a partial.

I know how to do this with Ruby on Rails but am unaware of how to set it up on a static page as we are only aloud the use of html5, css and javascript. Rendering a partial will improve working speed and keep clean code.

If this is how it is rendered in the html with Ruby on Rails

```
<%= render "shared/menu" %>
```

What would my line look like without the rails system.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe if you look at something like [HTML Imports](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/), this could solve your question. It caters for great flexibility and re-usability. You declare your partial import, simply by adding:

```
<link rel="import" href="/shared/menu.html">
```

to your html page.

Comment: will HTML imports work with github pages that serve static HTML?

Comment: HTML imports are now obsolete https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest using the [Middleman](https://github.com/middleman/middleman) Static site generator.  It is perfect if you are just wanting to build a static site and it is written in Ruby.  Their homepage is down, but I've linked their github page that has instructions of how to set it up.

Once setup, the code to render partials will be `<%= partial shared/menu %>`

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have to write it all from scratch. I wanted to know if a render is even possible with standard html?